# Should a software company's "scotch menu" be a red flag to not apply?

Tags: job-search, company-culture

I've been a big fan of a software company for a couple years now - I've bought their tools, brought them to my employers, developed a couple plug-ins, and recommend them when I can.

Recently, I met one of this company's devs at a conference, and she strongly encouraged me to apply there. So, I spent a little time reading up on the company itself, and discovered something that was a bit unsettling.

They have a "scotch menu" on their (public) website that advertises more scotch types than I even knew existed... and then they go to say, "if you are thinking about coming by our office for a meeting, please browse through our scotch menu - it can be an important preparation for any meeting at {company}."

Although I don't drink, I don't consider myself a prude, either...  but this just feels wrong on so many levels. It's one thing to have beer at the occasional office party, but this is just asking for harassment lawsuits. And the fact that they not only publicly post this menu, but encourage you to prepare for drinking in meetings with them, shows really poor judgment.

I've been impressed with just about everything else they do -- but this just seems like a huge let down, and a big red flag.

Am I over-thinking this? Should I still consider applying to a company that otherwise seems like a great fit for me?

Comment: Our company not only has scotch room but wine and beer fridges in the kitchen (there are also non-alcoholic drinks available). Does this mean we drink all the time? No. During work hours we behave responsibility (as all professionals should). After several hours of planning meetings do we have a drink yes (those things can be tiring and stressful). Is it a good gimmick for getting people into the office. Yes. How many of your friends if told there was a bar in the office would say. Ohhh I wished I worked there. Its a gimmick and a nice to have on the occasion.

Comment: PS. We did have a few bears during the world cup which we also played on the big screens in the kitchen.

Comment: I found the company page in question, and to be honest, the impression I get is not "this is a company of drunken misbehaviour", but rather "this is a company which pulls out all the stops to treat potential customers like kings".

Comment: You are obviously talking about Inedo. Have you read the [blog post on their Scotch Library](http://blog.inedo.com/2010/10/22/the-scotch-library/)? This isn't just any employee pushing it, it's the company founder. But I think you are misreading it -- it's a topic of conversation, not an invitation to get smashed.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Did the bears take all the beers? (I keep making the same typo, now that you've gotten me started...!)

Comment: It is possible for responsible adults who know their limit and have a drink with zero side-effects. Business is about engaging with people and not following a bunch of rules and regulations formed by lawyers who just cover their asses. Would you rather work for a company that secretly takes their clients out for steaks and strippers? Let the hipocricy end.

Comment: I get the feeling that by even asking this question that you may not be a good fit for the company.  No I don't think they are a bunch of drunkards.  Rather I think you are taking yourself a bit too seriously for their environment.

Answer (score 13):

> Am I overthinking this? Should I still consider applying to a company
>   that otherwise seems like a great fit for me?

While placing "if you are thinking about coming by our office for a meeting, please browse through our scotch menu - it can be an important preparation for any meeting at {company}" on a website says *something* about the type of culture at this company (or at least something about what they are trying to convey), it may not be as worrisome as you imagine.

It's easy to imagine an office of continuous, drunken parties, where everyone who doesn't drink is ostracized, where lawsuits are a regular occurrence, and where poor judgement runs rampant. But that's rather unlikely to be the case.

At least in the US, even the most "fun-loving" company cultures usually support individual choice. And most companies attempt to protect themselves against lawsuits.

Rather than jumping to a conclusion just by viewing their website, find out for yourself. Apply, get an interview, and determine for yourself the implications of this website statement. Ask pointed questions about what you observe - particularly about anything that would run counter to the culture you desire.

It might be a wild and crazy place. It might be a fun place where everyone is free to do what works for them. It might be a very professional place where people work hard during the day and some party hard after hours. Or it might just be a poor website.

Only you can decide if this is "wrong" to the extent that you couldn't work there.

(From the outside, it seems like a rather cool company to me.)

Answer (score 11):

You are way over thinking this in a way but it could still be a deal breaker for *you*.

Unlike many other fields at the moment, software development is an employee's field. What I mean by that is that there are more software dev jobs then there are qualified people to fill those jobs. Recently(ish) there was a big brouhaha about 1.7 million cloud-related jobs that went unfilled in 2012. This means that companies do things to separate themselves from competitors not just to customers(as companies in all fields must do) but also to prospective employees. This leads to things like 'ambassadors' of culture, providing breakfast tacos at all meetings, scotch lists on public websites, scooters for all employees, etc. These things are indicative of a companies culture and the types of people they have working for them. Most companies steer away from public discussions of alcohol being imbibed at the workplace, especially if they offer any sort of ongoing support or service. But not all. I know more than a few start-ups with a tap in the break room.

Why could this still be a deal breaker? If a company presenting that they drink alcohol like that bother you(and there is no judgement if it does because it would kind of squick me out as well) then maybe the culture wouldn't be a good fit. A somewhat silly, forcefully casual scotch meeting menu probably shouldn't be enough to discourage you from applying and finding out more about the company. But it should be encouragement to spend some time really understanding the company's culture and whether or not it would be a good fit for you.

Comment: I think I'd contact them and ask just how intrinsic this is to their company culture. If there'd be any pressure to drink alcohol, that's a concern. If they just pride themselves on being able to recognize and afford "the good stuff", it doesn't necessarily imply that people drink frequently of heavily. My approach would be similar to the old Western movie cliche... cue John Wayne voice: "Gimme a Sarsaparilla." (or whatever your favorite is) "You got a problem with that, partner?"

Comment: I think another time that it would be a deal breaker is if you are a person who struggles with addiction especially a recovering alcohalic who has a history of falling off the wagon or someone unable to maitain decorum when they get a few drinks in them.  A company where drinking in the office is practically expected is going to be an invitation to disaster for someone with those traits.

Answer (score 1):

**Alcohol in the workplace is no longer taboo if it's company sponsored**

If you brought in a bottle of scotch to a traditional workplace and started throwing it back like you were Don Draper you would rightly expect to be fired. This still holds true in the majority of corporate cultures, but [many progressive companies](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/joseph-nowinski-phd/alcohol-in-the-workplace-_b_1432533.html) have started to adopt work happy hours and allow drinking in the workplace an advertised perk of working for the company. Expectations are the same as they would be at a work party; that you don't drink to excess.

**Company Culture should always be compared with (and preferably match up with) your own preferences and beliefs**

You said you don't have any problem with the act of drinking at work, but maybe you do have a problem being associated with a company that advertises its workplace boozing. Weigh if that association would make you too uncomfortable or not. You said that they make a product you not only use, but recommend to others, their company policy on alcohol is either helping or benign. Only you can decide whether or not you would ultimately be able to fit in.